# I have used React-Router to redirect my page when I click on a link but it is not redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Quote from './components/Quote';
import './index.css'
import Abraham from './components/Abraham'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Quote />
        <h2>List of authors</h2>
      </div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Link to="/">Author1</Link>
        </div>
        <Routes>
          <Route exactpath="/" element={ <Abraham/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

abraham.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Abraham() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My name is Abraham</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to redirect to abraham when I click on author 1 but it is not happening. The page is not redirecting. I used React-Router-DOM to link it to another page which is `Abraham` which I have imported.

Comment: thank you i got it and i also changed it what i wanted was that i need the content of Abraham to be shown in a new page but after clicking it is just displaying in the same page pls help with this thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed a space here between `exact path`, The **exactpath** prop should be written as **exact** **path** with a space between them. See on the documentation: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool

```
import React from 'react';
import Quote from './components/Quote';
import './index.css';
import Abraham from './components/Abraham';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Quote />
        <h2>List of authors</h2>
      </div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Link to="/">Author1</Link>
        </div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Abraham />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Just Like he said, the attribute 'exactpath' is wrong, try simple path there. But this is unrelated to the working of link, only the component 'Abraham' is not rendered properly, so if you think the link is not working, you should check the URL of your application and check whether the link is working properly or not. If the link is not working then you should try restarting your server.

Comment: thank you so much after that it is working but it is not opening a new page where just My name is abraham should be displayed instead in the same page it is showing pls help with this

Answer (score 0):

If you would like for the `Abraham` route and component to be rendered separate from the `Quote` component, `h2` element, and links, then you should place the latter on a route so they are also conditionally rendered based on the URL path.

There is no `exact` prop for the `Route` component in React-Router v6, it should be removed since all routes are now *always* exactly matched using a [route ranking](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#ranking-routes) score.

Example:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={(
            <div>
              <Quote />
              <h2>List of authors</h2>
              <div>
                <Link to="/abraham">Author Abraham</Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/abraham" element={<Abraham />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much this is my first project i learned a lot thank you